# C++ float exceptions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I make some calculation of float numbers in my application. In some cases I got such numbers as -1.#J and 1.#R. What does this mean?

Comment: can you show relative code?

Comment: I hope you realize that with not even a single line of information it's going to be difficult to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Application performs a differential equation numerically. Code is very difficult and can't say anything. I want to know where these numbers may appear to know where to look.

Answer (score 3):

`-1.#J` is either NaN or inf: [What does floating point error -1.#J mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840081/what-does-floating-point-error-1-j-mean)

`1.#R` is underflow (exponent too small): http://www.windows-api.com/microsoft/VC-Language/31121018/1r-result-from-floating-point-arithmetic.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it's clarified a lot of troubles.