# How to get rid of 1.#J output in this code?

Tags: c, floating-point-conversion

I was wondering how to get rid of the 1.#J output that appears when it is run. I know it is related to the float mpg variable after the trip selection part. I am just beginning to use C, so any help is greatly appreciated. Also, the program is not yet finished.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN 80

float mpg, distance;

int main ( )
{
    int name[MAX_LEN];
    printf("Hello! Can you please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Okay, %s, Let's begin!\n", name);

    char answer;
    printf("%s, do you own a car? (Y or N):");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Great, welcome to the road trip calculator.\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("First we will need to know somethings about your car.\n");

        float gal_to_fill;

        printf("About how many gallons of gas does it take to fill it up: ");
        scanf("%f", &gal_to_fill);
        printf("%.2f\n",gal_to_fill);

        float mpg;
        printf("About how many miles can you drive per gallon: ");
        scanf("%f", &mpg);
        printf("%.2f\n",mpg);

        printf("Okay, now let's pick a location to travel to.\n");
        printf("We are going to start at ________\n");
        printf("Please pick a final destination:\n");
        printf("1. Boston, MA\n");
        printf("2. New York, NY\n");
        printf("3. Miami, FL\n");
        printf("4. Chicago, IL\n");
        printf("5. San Francisco, CA\n");
        break;
    }

    int trip;
    printf("Enter the number of your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &trip);

    while(trip == 1,2,3,4,5)
    {
        if (trip == 1)
        {
            float mpg;
            float distance = 141.9;
            printf("This trip is 141.9 miles\n");
            float gal_used;
            gal_used = distance/mpg;
            printf("%.2f\n",gal_used);
            break;
        }
        else if (trip == 2)
        {
            float distance = 343.6;
            printf("This trip is 343.6 miles\n");
            float gal_used;
            gal_used = distance/mpg;
            printf("%.2f\n", gal_used);
            break;
        }
        else if (trip == 3)
        {
            float distance = 1623.3;
            printf("This trip is 1623.3 miles\n");
            float gal_used;
            gal_used = distance/mpg;
            printf("%.2f\n", gal_used);
            break;
        }
        else if (trip == 4)
        {
            float distance = 1112.8;
            printf("This trip is 1112.8 miles\n");
            float gal_used;
            gal_used = distance/mpg;
            printf("%.2f\n", gal_used);
            break;
        }
        else if (trip == 5)
        {
            float distance = 3227.2;
            printf("This trip is 3227.2 miles\n");
            float gal_used;
            gal_used = distance/mpg;
            printf("%.2f\n", gal_used);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1.#J happens when you round 1.#INF to two decimal digits.  You get infinity by dividing by 0.  That extra mpg variable is not initialized, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems with the code. Why are you declaring so many `float mpg`s? `mpg` in the while loop will shadow the global version. Moreover in the trip selection part:

```
float mpg;
float distance = 141.9;
printf("This trip is 141.9 miles\n");
float gal_used;
gal_used = distance/mpg;
```

You're using `mpg` when it's not initialized and that invokes undefined behavior. The garbage in mpg can return anything including [`1.#J`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840081/995714). Same to other mpg variables in the other if blocks because it's the global one which was not initialized.

Another problem:

```
while(trip == 1,2,3,4,5)
```

That doesn't do what you think and the program will loop forever. Read [how the comma operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/995714) first. Change the loop to `while (trip >= 1 && trip <= 5)`